# Do question tags imply restrictions on the type of answers expected?

Tags: discussion, tags

Questions often include something like "*from a Roman Catholic perspective*", to explicitly restrict the types of answers that are appropriate.

Do the tags on questions imply a similar restriction, or do they simply indicate a relevant topic, or does it vary by tag?

For instance, with a question like [old testament - If the Holy Spirit came in Jesus, who is the "Holy Spirit" that David refers to?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/86154/if-the-holy-spirit-came-in-jesus-who-is-the-holy-spirit-that-david-refers-to), how should one interpret this tag:

> [pneumatology](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pneumatology) — "The theology, or doctrine, of the Holy Spirit. For the majority of Christians, the Holy Spirit is a person of the Holy Trinity – Father, Son, and Holy Spirit – and is Almighty God."

Does that mean that answers *must* be from a perspective that assumes this doctrine?

(Note that I'm not asking about this specific question, which is perhaps not the best example, only a handy recent one.  If it affects your answer, assume that "For the majority of Christians" isn't there.)

Answer (score 4):

Tags are often left out, so it is the question text that is definitive. And there have been many times when it looks like someone has added a tag to indicate a particular denominational scoping, but didn't mention it in the question text, and I've commented asking them to add it explicitly.

The pneumatology tag doesn't demand Trinitarian scoping; as it says, that is just the majority position.

The question you linked to is questionable, feel free to vote to close with the "Questions that can be answered from multiple Christian viewpoints are not allowed" close reason if you think it is not adequately scoped.

Comment: Yeah, when tags/title don't match is one instance where I feel pretty comfortable editing that into the question and not just badgering the OP to do it.